# How have we the impertinence to

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> How have we the impertinence to make these wild creatures forego their nature for ours, which at best they can but imitate?

Does Virginia Woolf mean “How can we be so impertinent to make..”? Or “How can we have the impertinence to make..”?

I do not understand why she wrote like this, because it sounds poetic??

Comment: But “How can we be so impertinent to make..” and “How can we have the impertinence to make..” mean the same thing. Except that the first one should have ***as*** between ***impertinent*** and ***to***. Note that "How have we the impertinence..." is just a formal, literary way of saying "How **can we** have the impertinence..." (there will rarely if ever be a context where you should use that construction yourself! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you tell me more about why I may not use the construction myself? I don't quite understand. Is it because it’s a strange construction?

Comment: It's not that strange to me - but I'm a pensioner with a degree in literature. And *literature* from a century or two ago is where I'd normally expect to come across it! I'm sure I've never actually *uttered* that construction in my life, though i may once or twice have used it in *writing* if I was feeling a bit "high and mighty, imperious, pretentious".

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!